solution-verification | Prove that the lines $BP,A'N,C'M$ are concurrent
The problem
Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a rectangular parallelepiped. We denote the projections of the vertex $B'$ on the diagonals $A'B, BC', A'C'$ by $M, N, P$.
$a)$ Show that $B'M$ and $B'N$ are the distances from point $B'$ to the planes $(A'BD')$ and $(ABC')$ respectively
$b)$ Prove that the lines $BP,A'N , C'M$ are concurrent
My idea
Drawing

For point $a)$ we know that because $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ is a rectangular parallelepiped $A'D' \perp (ABB'A')=> A'D' \perp MB'$ and we also know $MB' \perp A'B$ so we demonstrated that $MB' \perp (D'A'B)$ which means that the distance from $B'$ to $(A'BD')$ is $MB'$
The same thing we do for the other distance:
we know that because $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ is a rectangular parallelepiped $AB \perp (BCC'B')=> AB \perp B'N$ and we also know $B'N \perp BC'$ so we demonstrated that $B'N \perp (ABC')$ which means that the distance from $B'$ to $(ABC')$ is $B'N$
Now for point $b)$ I thought of using the reciprocal of the theorem of Ceva so I calculated the ratios determined by $M, N, P$ in triangle $BA'C'$ using the theorem of the cathetus.
$C'P=\frac{B'C'^2}{A'C'}, PA'=\frac{B'A'^2}{A'C'}$ so $\frac{PA'}{C'P}=\frac{B'A'^2}{B'C'^2}$
Analogous, we get that $\frac{PA'}{C'P}*\frac{C'N}{NB} \frac{MB}{A'M}= \frac{B'A'^2}{B'C'^2} \frac{B'C'^2}{B'B^2} \frac{B'B^2}{B'A'^2}=1$
so we proved that the lines $BP, A'N, C'M$ are concurrent
I'm unsure if I used the reciprocal of the theorem of ceva right or if I missed any info I should know before using it.
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Your solution looks correct to me.

$b)$
There is another solution which proves that $C'M\perp A'B, A'N\perp BC'$ and $BP\perp A'C'$.
Since $\triangle{BB'C'},\triangle{C'B'M}, \triangle{BB'M}$ are right triangles, we have
$$BC'^2=B'C'^2+BB'^2\tag1$$
$$C'M^2=B'C'^2+MB'^2\tag2$$
$$MB'^2=BB'^2-MB^2\tag3$$
From $(1)(2)(3)$, we get
$$BC'^2=C'M^2+MB^2\tag4$$
since
$$\begin{align}&BC'^2-C'M^2-MB^2
\\\\&=(B'C'^2+BB'^2)-(B'C'^2+BB'^2-MB^2)-MB^2
\\\\&=0\end{align}$$
It follows from $(4)$ that $C'M\perp A'B$.
Similarly, we have $A'N\perp BC'$ and $BP\perp A'C'$.

In part a, you can think also in terms of vectors. For example, vector $\vec{B'M}$ is a linear combination of $\vec i$ and $\vec k$, but $\vec{A'D'}$ is a multiple of $\vec j$, assuming $A'D'$ lies on $y$-axis. So, $A'D'\perp B'M.$ Similarly for others.
In part b, you could also use Euclid's theorem for right triangles. For example for the right triangle $\triangle BB'A'$ with altitude $B'M$ to the hypotenuse $BA'$:
$$BA'\,A'M=B'A'^2$$
$$BA'\,MB=B'B^2$$
Hence,
$$\frac{A'M}{MB}=\frac{B'A'^2}{B'B^2}.\tag1$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{BN}{NC'}=\frac{B'B^2}{B'C'^2}\tag2$$
and
$$\frac{C'P}{PA'}=\frac{B'C'^2}{B'A'^2}\tag3$$
If we multiply the above equations and use reverse Ceva's theorem, we conclude that $C'M, A'N, BP$ are conccurent.
